# How to ensure that my deployed azure function works?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I created an azure function app, and tested it locally where I using the console, was able to determine that the my application works, and does what it is supposed to do.

Now I have deployed it to Azure cloud, and started the service -  but I don't seem to have any indication on whether it is running, no logs showing what state it is in,
nothing.

How do i view the console application log for my application running in the azure cloud?

Comment: How is your function app triggered?

Answer (score 2):

I have an Azure Function App in the Portal which contains .NET Core 6 Http Trigger Function.

Now, it has run successfully 2 times.

You can observe the function app state in the Log Stream during the execution state and in idle state that there is no new trace, but your function host is running:

[image]

You can also observer the metric rates in Function App Overview blade, how many requests and when they came in last 30 minutes, 1 hour, etc. and you can see more metrics in Live Metrics blade from the Application Insights associated with that Function App.
[image]

You could also check any performance issues in the Function App using diagnostics.

Refer to [Azure Function App Diagnostics Overview doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-diagnostics) provided by Microsoft for knowing the issues, latency time related metrics and reports.